# How to count java nio connection number

Tags: java, nio

Java nio establishes lots of connections, How to do a count?

Comment: Java nio establishes lots of connections, How to do a count?

Comment: Do you want to know how many connections are active at any given time?

Answer (score 4):

Add 1 to a variable every time you accept a connection, and decrement it every time you close one.

Is this a trick question? ;-)

Comment: ...simple to implement.  Wherever you have your select() loop, check to see which branch accepts the connection and increment there.

Comment: @bruce dou - There is no way to do this apart from implementing a counter as suggested by @EJP.

Comment: @bruce dou: simple to say and trivial to do, hence my comment, unless of course your NIO code is complete spaghetti, which I can't do anything about.

But why do you need to know? I have written quite a number of production java.net and java.nio servers without ever needing a count of connected clients.

@Stephen C: there is actually another way via Selector, assuming you are using a Selector for all channels, and assuming you know how many ServerSocketChannels you have, or that you're prepared to traverse a data structure.

Comment: This other way is for each selector, to use selector.selectedKeys().size() I guess?